# Fill different colors in boxplot chart Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, boxplot

Can we fill colors like this in boxplot chart of Highcharts?

Please refer the image below:

[image: Boxplot Chart Highcharts]

Comment: Hello @Nimisha Jain. It is nice to see you here. As I see you are a new contributor and therefore I do not downvote your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking any question. P.s. I think you should ask this type of question in Meta Stackover Flow rather than here. Happy codings!

Comment: @rarblack - I don't think that this is a meta question, as it isn't a question about stackoverflow, per se

Comment: Not a meta question. But @Nimisha it would be good to show some example code from what you have already done and what kind of resources you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate point color based on some algorithm, for example:

```
chart: {
    type: 'boxplot',
    events: {
        load: function(){
            var points = this.series[0].points,
                color,
                length = points.length;

            Highcharts.each(points, function(point, i){
                color = 'rgb(255,' + Math.floor(i * 255 / length) + ', 0)'
                point.update({ fillColor: color }, false)
            });

            this.redraw();
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5k8wfrgc/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible to control the `fillColor` for a boxplot.

This is a demonstration to show you:
http://jsfiddle.net/mqunbjrs/

If you take a look at the highcharts API you will see that instead of using an array with the 6 plot values, you can use an object with named values: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.boxplot.data

instead of this:

```
data: [
[0, 3, 0, 10, 3, 5],
[1, 7, 8, 7, 2, 9],
[2, 6, 9, 5, 1, 3]
]
```

You would use this:

```
data: [{
    x: 1,
    low: 4,
    q1: 9,
    median: 9,
    q3: 1,
    high: 10,
    name: "Point2",
    fillColor: "#00FF00"
}, {
    x: 2,
    low: 5,
    q1: 7,
    median: 3,
    q3: 6,
    high: 2,
    name: "Point1",
    fillColor: "#FF00FF"
}]
```